# Data won't add into SQL Database

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, save

Code for SQL class as follows:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class sqlDatabase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PURCHASEREFUND = "_purchaserefund";  
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "_location";
public static final String KEY_SHOPTYPE = "_shoptype";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "_price";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "_date";
public static final String KEY_CARDUSED = "_cardused";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "receiptdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "receipttable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  

private receiptDBhelper receiptHelper;
private final Context receiptContext;
private SQLiteDatabase receiptDatabase;


private static class receiptDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public receiptDBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase rdb) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CARDUSED + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"          
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase rdb, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rdb.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(rdb);
    }

}

public sqlDatabase(Context c){
    receiptContext = c;
}

public sqlDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    receiptHelper = new receiptDBhelper(receiptContext);
    receiptDatabase = receiptHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;        
}

public void close(){
    receiptHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String purchaserefund, String shoptype,
        String location, String price, String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues dbcv = new ContentValues();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
    Date date = new Date();

    dbcv.put(KEY_PURCHASEREFUND, purchaserefund);
    dbcv.put(KEY_SHOPTYPE, shoptype);
    dbcv.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    dbcv.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
    dbcv.put(KEY_CARDUSED, cardused);
    dbcv.put(KEY_DATE, dateFormat.format(date));        

    return receiptDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, dbcv);
}

}
```

Relevant code for class that uses the SQL class:

```
String purchaserefund = precspurchaserefunds;
String shoptype = precsshoptypes;
String location = precsshoptypesselection[precsshoptypeselection];
String price = precsprices;
String cardused = precscarddetails[precscardusedselection];

sqlDatabase entry = new sqlDatabase(precs.this);

entry.open();

entry.createEntry(purchaserefund, shoptype, location, price, cardused);

entry.close();
```

As far as I'm aware, all the code is there and is correct, but for some reason when I look into an SQL Database Browser, there are no values inserted?

Comment: I don't know about SQLite but in general with transactional databases your changes can be thrown away if you forget to COMMIT them. The changes may also be invisible to all other sessions until you commit them.

Comment: I have multiple other SQL Databases that work without use of a "Commit" method, or string or anything of that matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is actually how you are checking the sql db content. Usually the db file is stored under /data/package_name/databases (or something like that, I don't remember the exact path), and without root access you cannot just read files inside that folder.

So with a SQL Database Browser that's probably the issue..

Try to access your data through your app and see if the data is there. Also, keep an eye on LogCat, there might be some warnings/errors related to the Db.

(PS. there's no need to call "commit"...)

Comment: You're exactly right, all of a sudden it started working randomly! Stupid SQL haha!

Answer (score 0):

There's no commit anywhere in that code. It's the first thing I look for because it's the thing I always forget when writing to databases or SharedPreferences. Lemme know if that's not the solution.